# Custom HTML to JSX loader fails on first token

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I made a simple html to jsx loader that takes advantage of jsxMagic's [HTMLtoJSX converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltojsx):

```
var jsxMagic = require('htmltojsx');

module.exports = function (content) {
    console.log("is this loader even getting called?") //(it is)
    var converter = new jsxMagic({
        createClass: false
    })  
    return converter.convert(content)
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run webpack, this function gets called on my html file requires, but it crashes on them immediately. What's strange to me, is that in the error dialogue it shows that the html has been correctly converted to JSX:

```
ERROR in ./Landing/landing-body.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <div>
|   <h5 className="product__title"> Your Product Name </h5>
|   <p> You can edit the html in landing-header.html
```

Is it the loader crashing, or perhaps some step after the loader has been called?

**Edit:** the converter.convert function is returning a string; this is probably the problem.